# How much RAM will Apache web server use if 10 users download a 100 MB file simultaneously?

Tags: apache-2.2, memory

I'm planning to buy a dedicated server from 1and1.com. There are many configurations on their site. Which one should I go for if I run the LAMP stack on CentOS and host files which users can download?

Comment: Uhhhhhh, me be try it and see? The answer is...Not much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](http://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Comment: I am a 'professional' system administrator working for a Pvt. Ltd. company. Unfortunately I don't have any seniors to consult. So I ask my doubts on Server Fault... why is this question unprofessional?

Answer (score 1):

As someone commented, the answer is "not much". But you can easily run a test using a simple PHP script on your computer to see more exact figures. However, it almost sounds like you are trying to do some kind of "load-testing" experiment. Downloading ten files is not going to give you a good idea of that. You might be better of trying several load-testing services concurrently to get a "feel" for it.

Try these:

1. http://loadimpact.com/ -->> my davourite
2. https://loader.io/

However, 10 guys downloading 100 Megabyte is hardly testing for load. You might need to consider a paralel load testing app like [Jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), as it hits apache directly. I might be mistaken when I say you will probably not offer "direct access" to downloads. That said, people will probably need to be authenticated. This means the direct download is not all you should be testing, but rather the entire end-to-end process from getting logged in to, to finishing a download.

This question can also become sort of redundant if you offload the file-saving to a cloud solution or use CDN. I think you might be sweating the small-stuff, and trying to optimize a system way before it's ready to be optimized (i.e. breaking a cardinal programming rule).

Comment: load testing gives me the bandwidth usage; I need the Apache RAM usage...